# Unable to Parse XML using Sp_XML_Prepare document when namespaces are present

Tags: sql, xml

I have an XML with namespaces. I am unable to parse it using sp_xml_preparedocument. I am able to parse if name spaces are removed from XML. Also I tried passing name spaces to Sp as parameter. But it is not returning any result.
Below is the Namespaces node.

```
'<SyncPurchaseOrder 
xmlns="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2 http://schema.inf.com/2.10.0/infOAGIS/BODs/Developer/SyncPurchaseOrder.xsd"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
releaseID="9.2"
versionID="2.10.0"
/>'
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading an XML with `sp_xml_preparedocument` is out-dated and should be replaced by the appropriate XPath-methods!

From your question I assume, that the real XML is bigger. This will only retrieve the `releaseID` to show the *how-to-do*...

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<SyncPurchaseOrder 
xmlns="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2 http://schema.inf.com/2.10.0/infOAGIS/BODs/Developer/SyncPurchaseOrder.xsd"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
releaseID="9.2"
versionID="2.10.0"
/>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2'
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi
                  ,'http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2 http://schema.inf.com/2.10.0/infOAGIS/BODs/Developer/SyncPurchaseOrder.xsd' AS xsd)
SELECT @x.value('(/SyncPurchaseOrder/@releaseID)[1]','varchar(max)') AS releaseID
```

Another way to get away without the namespaces was a wildcard:

```
SELECT @x.value('/*:SyncPurchaseOrder[1]/@releaseID','varchar(max)') AS releaseID
```

### UPDATE

If you have to stick with the out-dated `FROM OPENXML` you might do this

```
SELECT @XML = '<SyncPurchaseOrder 
xmlns="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2 http://schema.inf.com/2.10.0/infOAGIS/BODs/Developer/SyncPurchaseOrder.xsd"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
releaseID="9.2"
versionID="2.10.0"
/>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT
                           ,@XML
                           ,'<SyncPurchaseOrder xmlns:d="http://schema.inf.com/infOAGIS/2"/>' --name it "d" as "default", but can be any name

SELECT releaseID
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'd:SyncPurchaseOrder')
WITH 
(
releaseID   [nvarchar](20)  './@releaseID'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo for your reply. But cant it be achieved using sp_XML_Preparedocument?

Comment: Thanks Shnugo. I am able to process the XML file now. I will use latest approach for other time.

Comment: @Tesla, Good luck and Happy Coding!